# Pluggable Processing Unit in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

They have this example:

```
import tensorflow as tf   # TensorFlow registers PluggableDevices here.
tf.config.list_physical_devices()  # APU device is visible to TensorFlow.
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:APU:0', device_type='APU')]

a = tf.random.normal(shape=[5], dtype=tf.float32)  # Runs on CPU.
b =  tf.nn.relu(a)         # Runs on APU.
```

My question is straightforward: how do you tell which operation runs on which device ? `a` runs in CPU and `b` on the Pluggable device in this example.

[Source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu_plugins)

Answer (score 1):

In the example you cite, a fictitious "Awesome Processing Unit" (APU) providing the ReLU operation ("*for simplicity, this sample APU plug-in only has one custom kernel for ReLU*") was installed with:

```
# Install the APU example plug-in package
$ pip install tensorflow-apu-0.0.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Quote:

> *To use a particular device, like one would a native device in TensorFlow, users only have to install the device plug-in package for that device.*

After installing the APU plugin package, the APU  device can be used in Tensorflow as a native device.

A pluggable device comes with its own custom operations and kernels (see https://blog.tensorflow.org/2021/06/pluggabledevice-device-plugins-for-TensorFlow.html). And from the same blog:

> *PluggableDevice type: A new device type in TensorFlow which allows device registration from plug-in packages. It takes priority over native devices during the device placement phase.*

In the example you cite, the quote: "*APU plug-in only has one custom kernel for ReLU*", so for ReLU the APU will be chosen by default and

```
c = tf.nn.relu(a)  # Runs on APU
```

is equivalent to

```
with tf.device("/APU:0"):  
    c = tf.nn.relu(a)  # Runs on APU
```

I'm not sure how one can list the operations registered by a plugin device nor how devices are prioritized in the case of multiple plug-in devices.

Comment: You may just leave the line In general, a pluggable device comes with its own custom operations and kernels (see https://blog.tensorflow.org/2021/06/pluggabledevice-device-plugins-for-TensorFlow.html) since the rest has been linked in OP already.

Comment: Makes sense that each chip may be able to run only some operations.